Why does redirect not happen immediately when visiting a page with Next.js and next-auth?
I have a client-side component where I call the useSession method from the next-auth library, and if the user is not logged in, I redirect them. The problem is, when I visit the /clientmember page while logged out, the page opens and shortly after, it redirects asking me to log in. Why doesn't the redirect happen immediately when the page is first loaded?
"use client";

import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
import { redirect } from "next/navigation";

const Member = () => {
  const { data: session } = useSession({
    required: true,
    onUnauthenticated() {
      redirect("/api/auth/signin?callbackUrl=/ClientMember");
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Member Client Session</h1>
      <p>{session?.user?.email}</p>
      <p>{session?.user?.role}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Member;


you should paste the code of /clientmember

I handle it i fixed my problem.
